# jQuery on click not working on elements inside Shadow DOM (Safari)

Tags: jquery, safari, shadow-dom

I wasn't able to find much info about this when I did a search, so decided I would make a new question. I've been trying to use jQuery for handling on click on certain elements, it works fine on the page itself (which I'm not interested in), my code makes a shadow DOM/root, which is where the elements I need to handle are in, but when I click, lets say a h2 element inside that shadow DOM, nothing happens, when it's in the document all is good. What can I do?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'h2', function() {
    // do something
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

I'm not really sure if this has something to do with the browser being Safari, or if it's because it's a Safari extension, but nonetheless it's JavaScript/jQuery, so Im guessing there can't be much differences from lets say Chrome.

I'm creating the shadow dom like this:

```
shadow = document.querySelector('#container')
    .attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
```

I've declared shadow in the top of the code, so don't mind that.

**Edit: This seems to be working**

```
shadow.getElementById('containerBox').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);
        alert(e.target.className);
        alert(e.target.getAttribute("data-origin"));
    }, true);
```

Comment: Does this work? `document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) { alert('click') }, true);`

Comment: It does, also inside the shadow dom, tested something similar earlier, but can only seem to get the parent element, not the actual child element clicked, even with event.stopPropagation :/

Comment: So you only want to listen for clicks inside the shadow-root, correct? You can either attach an event listener to the shadow-root node (or a container inside) or you can attach the listener to the top document like i showed, and in the event function you can just check if the click was from inside a shadow dom.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the code from document.body to shadow. Still, it doesn't change the fact, that I can't see the actual child element clicked, only the parent, as there is no path in Safari. Sure, I can detect if the click came from within the shadow dom, but that won't help me :p

Comment: What does the code inside the shadow look like? If you attach the listener to something inside, you can get the actual click element with event.target. I don't think you can attach the listener to the shadow itself because it's a document fragment, but if you have a container element inside you can attach it to that.

Comment: Yeah, I know when you do it on a specific element it works fine, however, not on dynamically added elements (might have forgotten to mention that..) and where it has to be by class and not id.

Comment: Yeah but the shadow is just created once. If you create the shadow and insert `<div id="container">` (for example)  into the shadow root, you can attach a listener to that. After this you can dynamically create whatever you want inside and it will bubble up to the container where you have the listener attached.

Comment: @qwerty I was able to make that work in Chrome since it supports the "path" object,  but I don't see how to make it work in Safari when it can't seem to get the child elements. Can u post an example?

Comment: @Supersharp Negative.

Comment: @Supersharp Uhm, how will this help my question? Shadow dom works on Safari (unlike Firefox, which seems to be what u referred to)

Comment: Anyway, I believe u guys are both getting away from the question I asked. Why is it that the jquery code above doesn't work on elements in the shadow dom?